# Remove all the characters after a '_' in column name of r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a dataframe as follows :

```
   Ax_ghx By_jkgf YTz8_hjks gh3_hjhd
a  1  2  3  4
b  3  4  5  6
```

How to remove all the characters after '_'  which results in a dataframe as follows :

```
  Ax By YTz8 gh3
a 1  2  3  4
b 3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data example

```
 df <- data.frame(Ax_ghx = 1, By_jkgf = 1, YTz8_hjks = 1,gh3_hjhd = 1)
```

#### Tidyverse approach

```
library(dplyr)  


df %>% rename_with(.fn = ~sub(x = .,"_.*",""))

  Ax By YTz8 gh3
1  1  1    1   1
```

#### Base R

```
names(df) <- sub(x = names(df),"_.*","")

df 
              
  Ax By YTz8 gh3
1  1  1    1   1
```